# Date change frustration

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that takes a date, which is in a variable, checks if the day is the 5th or 20th. If it's the 5th it changes the variable to the 20th of the same month. If it's the 20th, it moves it to the 5th of the next month.

This code is working as expected for Jan, Feb, Nov, and Dec. The other months its a day short (it puts it on the 4th or 19th).

The only thing I can notice is that those months have day light savings time but that should not matter? I am not sure what I am missing.

This is not all the code just the relevant part. The variable date1 IS defined, I just did not put it in here to keep it simple.

What am I missing?

```
if (date1 instanceof Date){
var day = date1.getUTCDate();var month = date1.getMonth();var year = date1.getFullYear()

if (day === 5){date1 = new Date(year, month, 20)}
else if (day ===20){date1 = new Date(year, month+1, 5)}
sheet.getRange("V3").setValue(date1)
```

}

date1 is a variable with a date in it.  If the date is on a 5th, make it the 20th.  If it's on the 20th make it the 5th of next month.  Looks like both are doing the same thing for the same months.  Only Jan\Fab\Nov\Dec work right

Comment: Date methods like `getDate` will return the current day/month/whatever based on the *browser's time zone*, which is why `getUTCDate` exists, and should show the 20th.

Comment: Can you show your actual result and your expected result on your post?

Comment: @Century I posted what the result and expected in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of daylight savings.  Added

```
// Apply daylight saving time offset
```

evanNextCheck.setMinutes(evanNextCheck.getMinutes() + dstOffset);

and

```
// Apply daylight saving time offset
```